# java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00911: invalid character in oracle 11g

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

I get the error in the title when I try to insert data into the oracle 11g database. Here is the table details and the function which I use:

[image]

```
private static void insertDetails() throws Exception{
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
        Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe","AJ204","pract");  
        System.out.println("Connected database successfully...");
        PreparedStatement ps=null;
        ps=con.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO `STUDENT_PERS_DETAILS`(ENROLL_NO,NAME,GENDER,PERMANENT_ADDRESS_HOUSE_NO.,PERMANENT_ADDRESS_STREET_NAME,PERM._ADDR._NEAREST_LANDMARK,PERM._ADDR._PINCODE,CONTACT_NO.,EMAIL_ADDRESS,AADHAR) VALUE (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
        System.out.println("Enter the student's details");
        System.out.println("Enroll_No:");
        long enroll_no=sc.nextLong();
        ps.setLong(1, enroll_no);
        System.out.println("Name:");
        sc.nextLine();
        String name2=sc.nextLine();
        ps.setString(2, name2);
        System.out.println("Gender:");
        String gndr=sc.nextLine();
        ps.setString(3, gndr);
        System.out.println("Permanent Address details:");
        System.out.println("\tHouse No.:");
        String house_no=sc.nextLine();
        ps.setString(4, house_no);
        System.out.println("\tStreet Name:");
        String street=sc.nextLine();
        ps.setString(5, street);
        System.out.println("\tNearest Landmark:");
        String landmark=sc.nextLine();
        ps.setString(6,landmark);
        System.out.println("\tPincode:");
        long pincode=sc.nextLong();
        ps.setLong(7, pincode);
        System.out.println("Contact No.:");
        long cntct_no=sc.nextLong();
        ps.setLong(8, cntct_no);
        System.out.println("Email:");
        String email=sc.nextLine();
        ps.setString(9,email);
        System.out.println("Aadhaar No.:");
        long aadhaar_no=sc.nextLong();
        ps.setLong(10, aadhaar_no);
        System.out.println("Set success");
        int n=ps.executeUpdate();
        System.out.println("Updated");
        ps.close();
        con.close();
    }
```

Comment: How about formatting this code?

Comment: if you could make it slightly easier to read, that would be grand. Also remove the image link and put in in the question

Comment: `\`STUDENT_PERS_DETAILS\`` is an invalid identifier in SQ: https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/sql_elements008.htm#SQLRF51129

Comment: change VALUE to VALUES

Comment: Try to use any sql client application to generate error free query

Comment: Oracle doesn't use backticks (that is a MySQL/MariaDB specific deviation from the SQL standard). If you meant to quote that table name, you should use double quotes (so `"STUDENT_PERS_DETAILS"`).

Comment: you mean removing the single quotes ? i did that and it gives java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-01747: invalid user.table.column, table.column, or column specification

Comment: Your table column names have periods in them - `PERM._ADDR._NEAREST_LANDMARK` etc. You will have to enclose those in double-quotes too - and those need to be escaped within the Java string. (And ask whoever designed this what they were thinking...) Did you try to run your statement directly (e.g. via SQL*Plus) to see if it was valid?

Comment: It worked i removed underscores,periods and shortened the column and table names and it worked. Thanks everyone ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your SQL statements turns out this:

```
INSERT INTO `STUDENT_PERS_DETAILS` (
    ENROLL_NO,
    NAME,
    GENDER,
    PERMANENT_ADDRESS_HOUSE_NO.,
    PERMANENT_ADDRESS_STREET_NAME,
    PERM._ADDR._NEAREST_LANDMARK,
    PERM._ADDR._PINCODE,
    CONTACT_NO.,
    EMAIL_ADDRESS,
    AADHAR) 
VALUE 
    (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)
```

It has several errors:

- Table name must not be enclosed by back-ticks, remove them
- Column names must not containdots `.` (unless double quoted, but this is not useful)
- Keyword `VALUE` must be `VALUES`